# Visual Studio linker errors trying to use static lib in DLL (LNK2038, LNK2005)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, static-libraries

In Visual Studio 2013, I am trying to use a static library (MySQL Connector/C) in another static library (say "MyConn"), and to use that (MyConn) in a DLL project. The static libraries build find, but attempting to build the DLL produces linker errors like these:

```
MyConn.lib(plugin_client.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MDd_DynamicDebug' in doit.obj
LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __CrtCheckMemory already defined in msvcrtd.lib(MSVCR120D.dll)
```

In project properties, `Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Code Generation --> Runtime Library`, all three projects have the same setting for their respective build types:

- Debug   - `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)`
- Release - `Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)`

What other settings might fix this?

Comment: `in doit.obj`  Please check that particular module's settings.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, the Code Generation settings of `doit.cpp` are the same as for the project.

Answer (score -1):

Your `doit.obj` is linked with different MS runtime library than MyConn.lib. Check your project settings and make sure that runtime library is set to `Multithreaded Debug` or `Multithreaded` for both projects.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify the settings of the projects. I see the same when I look at the properties of `doit.cpp`. Is there some other way the one module could differ?